# Class not found with composer psr4

Tags: composer-php

I'm using the composer to load a simple controller class bu I'm facing a problem with the autoloader. It will give me always this error: 
`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Controller' not found`.

My composer.json file looks like this:

```
{
    "require": {
        "nikic/fast-route": "^1.3"
    },
    "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
        "Controllers\\": "src/Controllers/"
      }
    }
}
```

and in my project root I have the src folder with the Controllers subfolder inside it.

I'm requiring the autoload and using the `Controllers` namespace inside my class.
On the index where I'm loading the controller using fast route router, I have after the autoloader the `use \Controllers\Controller;` statement.

What's wrong with my implementation?

here is the full code:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Controllers\Controller;

$dispatcher = FastRoute\simpleDispatcher(function(FastRoute\RouteCollector $router) {

    $router->addRoute('GET', '/', 'Controller/index');
    $router->addRoute('GET', '/azienda', 'Controller/about');
    $router->addRoute('GET', '/servizi', 'Controller/services');
    $router->addRoute('GET', '/contatti', 'Controller/contacts');

});

// Fetch method and URI from somewhere
$httpMethod = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

// Strip query string (?foo=bar) and decode URI
if(false !== $pos = strpos($uri, '?')){
    $uri = substr($uri, 0, $pos);
}
$uri = rawurldecode($uri);

$routeInfo = $dispatcher->dispatch($httpMethod, $uri);
switch ($routeInfo[0]) {
    case FastRoute\Dispatcher::NOT_FOUND:
        // ... 404 Not Found
        break;
    case FastRoute\Dispatcher::METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED:
        $allowedMethods = $routeInfo[1];
        // ... 405 Method Not Allowed
        break;
    case FastRoute\Dispatcher::FOUND:
        $handler = $routeInfo[1];
        $vars = $routeInfo[2];
        list($class, $method) = explode("/", $handler, 2);
        call_user_func_array([new $class, $method], $vars);
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using variables as class name (like `new $class`), they need do contain full qualified name. In your case `$class` contains `Controller` while FQN of this class is `Controllers\Controller`.

> One must use the fully qualified name (class name with namespace prefix). Note that because there is no difference between a qualified and a fully qualified Name inside a dynamic class name, function name, or constant name, the leading backslash is not necessary.
>
> <sub>https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php</sub>

You need to put FQN in your dispatcher config:

```
$router->addRoute('GET', '/', 'Controllers\Controller::index');
$router->addRoute('GET', '/azienda', 'Controllers\Controller::about');
$router->addRoute('GET', '/servizi', 'Controllers\Controller::services');
$router->addRoute('GET', '/contatti', 'Controllers\Controller::contacts');
```

And handle dispatch results in this way:

```
case FastRoute\Dispatcher::FOUND:
    $handler = $routeInfo[1];
    $vars = $routeInfo[2];
    list($class, $method) = explode('::', $handler, 2);
    call_user_func_array([new $class, $method], $vars);
    break;
```

Comment: I didn't know about this, also because normally if the class is on the same file it will work without problem (while I develop and debug, usually I have all the code on one file). If you can link me the php manual about, I will go deeper about. Thanks for the clarification. PS: Why you have called the methods like they were static?

Comment: You can use whatever name you want, as long you will be able co convert it to correct callable - `::` is safe for `explode` and it is convention used for FQN of method names (including non-static) by PHP (`__METHOD__` will return such string).